# Visual Studio VB.Net form requires the User to install VB.Net-How to avoid?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vb6

I have developed a simple form which don't have any .Net requirements but the published forms is not opening in users system and showing message to install .Net framework in users systems.

But this issue is happening with Visual Studio only and if I create the same form in VB6 then the form is working nicely without any .Net installation requirement.

Any suggestion about how to get rid of this .Net installation requirement (in Users Systems) in VS forms?

Comment: you can't. you need .NET installed

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I understand I can't but why this requirement made mandatory to install .Net when there is no .Net related things are used?  Seems stupid requirement made mandatory in VS by Microsoft.

Comment: Becasue and VB6 and VB .NET are completely different products. It´s almost like JavaScript and Java. Even if you had a VB .NET program which has an empty Main method only you would have to install .NET (Runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both VB6 and VB.NET have prerequisites. It just happens that VB6 is *so old* that the required prerequisites are already included in all operating systems still in use ([Windows NT 4 SP4 and above](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=125561)).

You say that you "don't use any .net related things". That's not true. VB.NET itself is part of the .NET framework, as well as the UI library you use (probably WinForms).

If you need your application to run without prerequisites, you could target an earlier version of the framework: [.NET 2.0 is included in Vista and above, .NET 3.5 is included in Windows 7 and above.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/)

Comment: Thanks for enlightening my knowledge about VS.  The problem is that most of them still using XP so asking them to update .Net Framework is a mysterious thing to them.

Comment: @Sixthsense: If they are still using XP, I hope they are not connected to the Internet. Since XP no longer receives security updates, that's like leaving your car unlocked in a dangerous area with all your personal documents on the back seat. If they are your customers, sell them OS upgrades!

Comment: @Sixthsense you can include the .NET framework in your program's installation package. As an example, you can use NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System...it's free) as your setup program and find installation scripts that do it for you. It can detect which version the user has and download/install it if needed.

Comment: @Chase Rocker, Thanks for sharing the info about NSIS program.  I successfully downloaded it and now searching in google about how to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

The System.Windows.Form object is part of .Net.  So is every one of the controls you're using on your form.  So, if you develop any kind of form in VS (later than VS 6) you are using the .Net framework whether you realize it or not.  In this case, it isn't one of Microsoft's arbitrary requirements.

You should also realize that the VB6 Runtime module has to be installed on the target machine for the VB6 version of your form to work properly, too.  So, if it runs fine, it's only because that module happens to already be registered on your target machine.  That might not always be the case.

Comment: So it is a pre-planned action taken in VS to force users to upgrade the users to the higher version of Widows-XP

Comment: @Sixthsense: Not really: It just happens that .NET 2.0 was released *after* Windows XP; thus, Windows XP only includes .NET 1.0. Newer versions of .NET framework (up to 4.0) can be downloaded for Windows XP for free and might even be offered as "optional upgrade" in Windows Update.

Comment: Thanks once again for your extended knowledge sharing :)